# Objects Referential transparency for functional programming in Java 8

Tags: functional-programming, java-8

I have been studying functional programming and one of the requirements is that they are pure in the sense that they only return the computed value and not touch anything else or throw exceptions, they don't also access shared mutable objects - this makes them inherently thread safe.

So then what  would be the correct approach to implement a pure function that takes objects as arguments rather than primitive values. Would I have to deep clone them when passing to a function ?

Comment: As long as you don't want the objects to look different, you don't need to clone anything.

Comment: You don't need to clone anything *before* doing something functional*ish*. Instead, you should decide when to create a new instance or return one of the arguments. An example would be returning statistics about sells. You have a function that receives a list of sells and returns an object with the statistics (i.e. total, average, min, max etc). Why would you ever want to deep-clone the list of sells?

Answer (score 2):

If the function is a pure function, i.e. does not modify existing objects, whether they are passed as parameters or lying around somewhere else, there is no sense is copying or cloning the argument objects.

You could also see it the other way round: if cloning arguments is necessary, the invoked code is not functional and cloning the arguments doesn’t turn it into functional code, it’s actually working around a design flaw.

In the best case, you would be working with immutable objects which prevent modifications intrinsically, however, using immutable objects doesn’t change the way how the functional code should behave, they just enforce some aspects of it. When a particular class does not offer immutable objects, you can still use it in the right way, without the need to re-implement it in an immutable way.

Generally, it is not a good idea to develop your code assuming that all other code will misbehave and that it was your code’s task to solve the issues of that misbehavior.

Comment: `it is not a good idea to develop your code assuming that all other code will misbehave and that it was your code’s task to solve the issues of that misbehavior` genius remark! I should re-direct some of the code-reviewers at my workplace here...

Answer (score 0):

The objects should ideally be immutable. Immutability and functional programming go hand-to-hand.

If having all immutable objects isn't feasible, yes, you would ideally need to make deep copies of everything to ensure changes to them don't effect anything else outside of the function.

Comment: Could you point me to any material that have done this sort of implementation ? I could only find examples using primitive types. Or should I just limit my cases for primitive types

Comment: @jtkSource Examples of immutable non-primitives classes?

Comment: Sorry to ask but I was just curious how its done in case the objects were mutable (non-primitive) or should I just rethink if I should be using the Functional paradigm in this case?

Comment: @jtkSource It's ok, I'm just not sure what your question is. Are you asking for examples of deep-copying mutable objects, or creating immutable objects?

Comment: neither, in case of functional programming in java 8 if ever I was to pass an mutable object to a function 1) am I making a design mistake 2) if not I will need to convert to a immutable/deep cloned object - is there any easy way to do this - if not it would seem to #1 was correct.

Comment: @jtkSource If you're going for a purely functional approach, yes, I would say passing a mutable object to a function is a poor design choice, as you're allowing side effects into and out of the function. Deep cloning isn't easy to do though iirc. Java has a Cloneable interface, but again, iirc, it's considered broken. Honestly, if you want to do functional programming on the JVM, look up Clojure. It's a functional language that compiles to Java byte code (or JavaScript). Everything (nearly) is already immutable, so it makes this question a non-issue.

Comment: @jtkSource Java isn't a very good language to try to program functionally in. It's recently added some functional aspects, but it still has a long way to go before you can naturally program FP style in it.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking the same.